# Using chain rule to represent second order derivatives

Tags: derivatives

Is this methodology correct
$$\frac{d^{2}r}{dt^2}=\frac{d^{2}r}{dx^2}*\frac{dx^2}{d^{2}\beta}*\frac{d^2\beta}{dt^2}$$
r is interms of x $\beta$ rotates at constant velocity, and x is independent variable and t is time.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry.. you can use it,

Comment: So we have that $r$ depends on $x$ and $t$, right? And $\beta$?

Comment: No. See, e.g., Example 5 of http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx .

Comment: No it's not correct.

Comment: You could do this for the first derivative, but this formula fails for higher derivatives, think of $f(x)=x$ and $x=t^2$.  Using the formula above, you would get $0$, which is not correct.  You could, however, apply the derivative to the formula for the first derivative, but you'll need the chain rule and the product rule for higher derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no careless mistake really long and was in a hurry ,

Answer might be

$\implies \frac{d^2r}{dx^2}*\left(\frac{dx}{d\beta}\right)^2*\left(\frac{d\beta}{dt}\right)^2+\frac{dr}{dx}*\frac{d^2x}{d\beta^2}*\left(\frac{d\beta}{dt}\right)^2+\frac{dr}{dx}*\frac{dx}{d\beta}*\frac{d^2\beta}{dt^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Although you have not made it clear what $\beta$ actually represents, if it is rotating with constant velocity, as you say, then the time derivatives would be zero, so the left hand side would be zero. As others have said, the given expression is not correct. The equivalent expression for first derivatives would be correct.

Comment: $\beta$ depends on time